# Image downloaded from server is blurred in ImageView

Tags: imageview, android-volley, universal-image-loader

I am using `Universal Imageloader` and `Volley` to download an image from my server. Both result in a blurred image. It doesn't make a difference that the width and the height of the image is smaller or larger than the resolution of my screen. I tried uploading the image I am trying with in low and high resolution as well. The image is always displayed blurred.

**Imageloader:**

```
optionsImg = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
           .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage)
           .cacheOnDisc(true)
           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
           .cacheInMemory(true)
           .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
           .considerExifParams(true)
           .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(1555))
           .build();

imageLoader.displayImage("http://www.mywebsite.com/Images/image.png", iv_bucket, optionsImg, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
      boolean cacheFound;

      @Override
      public void onLoadingStarted(String url, View view) {
           List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtil.findCacheKeysForImageUri(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
           cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();

           if (!cacheFound) {
                 File discCache = DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
                 if (discCache != null) {
                       cacheFound = discCache.exists();
                  }
           }
      }

       @Override
       public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {}

       @Override
       public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, final View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
           if (cacheFound) {                                                                           ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, (ImageView) view, optionsImg);
           }

      }
});
```

**Volley:**

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader nil = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
nil.get("http://www.mywebsite.com/Images/image.png", new ImageListener() {

       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.e("IMG", "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
       }

       @Override
       public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
           if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                 Log.e("IMG_BG", "Image Load Success");
                 iv_bucket.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
           }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so lame. My phone cached the low quality images so even if I increased the quality it displayed the cached photos